# Accumulations of ajaxSuccess

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".btn_tab").click(function() { 
        var ids = new Array();
        $i=0;
        $(this).ajaxSuccess(function(e) {
            alert($i);
            $( ".tab-content .active table tbody tr td a.elusive-align-justify" ).each(function() {
                $url = $(this).attr('href');
                //console.log($url);

                var divided = $url.split("/");
                var id = divided[2];

                //console.log(id);
                ids.push(id);   
            });
                console.log(ids);

                $i++;
        });
```

- In the first tab I get alert 0,
- in the second alert 0, alert 1,
- in third alert 0, alert 1, alert 2, and so on.

The correct should be always alert 0

I think the problem is related with event listener, because i only do one xhr request for each click.

If i use `this.removeEventListener(e);` i get an error and everything works fine. `return false`, `return` or `this.removeEventListener('click', e, false);` don't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ajaxSuccess` is an event listener, and you're binding a new one on every click. Move it outside the click handler.

Comment: i appreciate if you can elaborate more

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing on my phone right now, but I can do that later. What are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: And where are you doing the actual Ajax request? Looks like you should be using a regular `success` event, instead of ajaxSuccess.

Comment: You are correct, the only thing that i need is data.responseText from ajaxSuccess. thanks